# Every subring of a field is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

When I was trying to prove the following theorem:

> Theorem. Let $E$ be an extension field of the field $F$ and let $a \in E$
> .If $a$ is algebraic over $F$, then $F(a) \cong F[x]/ \langle p(x)\rangle$
> , where $p(x)$ is a polynomial in $F[x]$ of minimum degree
> such that $p(a)=0$. Moreover, $p(x)$ is irreducible over $F$.

I considered an homomorphism $\phi: F[x] \longrightarrow F(a) $ such that $\text{Ker} \phi \neq 0$, so $\text{ker} \phi=\langle p(x)\rangle$. As $F[x]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain, we have that $p(x)$ is irreducible.

Now by the First Isomorphism Theorem $F[x]/ \langle p(x)\rangle \cong \text{Im} \phi \leq F(a).$ Now it is claimed that $\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a prime ideal of $F[x]$ becuase $\text{Im}\phi$ is an integral domain.

My question comes from this last sentence, how can be proved that:

> Theorem. Every subring R of a field F is an integral domain.

So we have to prove R to be commutative with unit. It is clear that it is commutative because if there exist $a,b\in R$ such that $ab\neq ba$, then like $R\subset F$ we have that $a,b\in F$ are no commutative which is a contradiction.

My problem comes when proving that R necessarily has a unit. So I tried to build my counterexample, let $F=\mathbb{Q}$, we consider $R={2\mathbb{Z}}$ wich is a subring because it is closed under subtraction and multiplication.

Can someone tell my why is my counterexample wrong and how it is proved that $1\in R$?

Comment: What is your definition of subring?

Comment: A subset S of a ring R is a subring of R if S is itself a ring with the
operations
of R.

Comment: And does your ring definition include rings without an unit?

Comment: No, it is not the standard definition of a ring. Most authors force rings to have an unit. If you admit non-unitary rings, then your counterexample works and not every subring of a field is an integral domain.

Comment: My bad, I was talking about Joseph Gallian definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample is great.

What happens is that $\text{Im}\phi$ is an integral domain not only because it is a subring of $F(a)$, from which you obtain commutativity, but also from the fact that $1 \in F[x]/ \langle p(x)\rangle$ . This comes from the fact that $ 1 \in F[X]$ as F is a field and because $$\langle p(x)\rangle = \{r(x)p(x):r(x) \in F[x]\}$$ and $$F[x]/ \langle p(x)\rangle = \{f(x) + r(x)p(x):r(x) \in F[x]\}$$ you choose $r(x)=0 \in F[x]$ and you finally have that $\text{Im}\phi$ is an integral domain so $\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a prime ideal.